# как задать в layer-list каждой стороне свой цвет?

Tags: java, android

```
Т.е левая сторона синий цвет, правая, вершина и низ должны быть **#000000**
```

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/toolbar_left_color"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/light_gray"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!-- Верхняя граница -->
  <item
    android:bottom="15dp"
    android:left="15dp"
    android:right="15dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Нижняя граница -->
<item
    android:left="15dp"
    android:right="15dp"
    android:top="15dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Левая граница -->
<item
    android:bottom="15dp"
    android:right="15dp"
    android:top="15dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#0000FF" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Правая граница -->
<item
    android:bottom="15dp"
    android:left="15dp"
    android:top="15dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
</item>


<!-- Цвет фона внутри -->
<item
    android:bottom="15dp"
    android:left="15dp"
    android:right="15dp"
    android:top="15dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```